# the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wshttpbinding

I have a sample web application that consumes the wcf services with web.config has

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TheBindingConfig">
      <security mode="None" >
         <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
    <message establishSecurityContext="false" />    
    </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>   
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/myservice/Service.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TheBindingConfig"
        contract="myservice.IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and the wcf service configuration file is as below

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="myservice.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="myservice.IService">
                    <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

note service is created with the namespace "**myservice**"

i am error responses as

```
The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IService/GetUserDetails' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.
```

and stack trace as

```
[FaultException: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IService/GetUserDetails' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9439503
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +345
   sampleuserservice.IService.GetUserDetails(String Username) +0
   sampleuserservice._Default.BindUserDetails() +57
   sampleuserservice._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +90
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

note: service is running correctly as expected

i guess the there is a mapping issue between the above webconfig files

waiting for your valuable responses and sugessions

Comment: Does the service work when you call it from WCFTestClient or SoapUI?

Comment: @MaxS-Betclic WCF Test Client in Visual Studio

Comment: @MaxS-Betclic with out namespace it working fine

Comment: WCFTestClient.exe can be found there: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe"`. What do you mean by _"with out namespace it working fine"_

Answer (score 0):

if the service can be consumed by any kind of client (.net, soapui) then publish the working soap request (headers + body) and the non working one. you can use fiddler or wcf logs to get the message. if the service is not wokring at all then my guess is that it is because the client is configured not to use security at all (security mode ="none") and the server has no binding configuration, so the default is used and the default has some security on it.